# Shared Calendar with Outlook loaded from Citrix

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following function in Excel to access shared calendar folders in Outlook and list all certain appointments (identified from its subject) within specified date range.
The code seems doesn't work as expected as Outlook is loaded from Citrix server.
I'm not so sure about this and need somebody's help on how to solve this.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetColleagueAppointments(dtStartAppt As Date, dtEndAppt As Date, strUserName As String) 'As String
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Purpose:      List down all colleague's client meetings between date range
'
' Inputs:       dtStartAppt         Start date to search
'               dtEndAppt           End date to search
'               strUserName         Colleague calendars to search
'
' Assumptions:  * User must have access to the appropriate shared calendars in
'                 Outlook
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application    ' Outlook
Dim objNS As NameSpace                  ' Namespace
Dim OLFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder        ' Calendar folder
Dim OLAppt As Object                    ' Single appointment
Dim OLRecip As Outlook.Recipient        ' Outlook user name
Dim OLAppts As Outlook.Items            ' Appointment collection
Dim oFinalItems As Outlook.Items
Dim strRestriction As String                    ' Day for appointment
Dim strList() As String                 ' List of all available timeslots
Dim dtmNext As Date                     ' Next available time
Dim intDuration As Integer              ' Duration of free timeslot
Dim i As Integer                        ' Counter
Dim lr As Long, r As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

'FastWB True
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Meeting List")

Const C_Procedure = "GetColleagueAppointments"    ' Procedure name
'This is an enumeration value in context of getDefaultSharedFolder
Const olFolderCalendar As Byte = 9

strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & _
                    Format$(dtStartAppt, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") _
                    & "' AND [End] <= '" & _
                    Format$(dtEndAppt, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") & "'"

' loop through shared Calendar for all Employees in array
Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

With ws
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OLRecip = objNS.CreateRecipient(strUserName)

    OLRecip.Resolve

    'If OLRecip.Resolved Then
        'Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)
        Set OLFldr = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(OLRecip, olFolderCalendar)
    'End If

    ' calendar not shared
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        '#   Employee    Date    Start   End Client  Agenda  Location
        r = Last(1, .Columns("G")) + 1
        .Range("F" & r).Value = r - 1                           '#
        .Range("G" & r).Value = strUserName                       'Employee
        .Range("H" & r).Value = "Calendar not shared" 'Format(dtStartAppt, "d-mmm-yyyy")   'Date
        .Range("I" & r).Value = "Calendar not shared"           'Start
        .Range("J" & r).Value = "Calendar not shared"           'End
        .Range("K" & r).Value = "Calendar not shared"           'Client
        .Range("L" & r).Value = "Calendar not shared"           'Agenda
        .Range("M" & r).Value = "Calendar not shared"           'Location

        GoTo ExitHere
    End If

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set OLAppts = OLFldr.Items

    ' Sort the collection (required by IncludeRecurrences)
    OLAppts.Sort "[Start]"

    ' Make sure recurring appointments are included
    OLAppts.IncludeRecurrences = True

    ' Filter the collection to include only the day's appointments
    Set OLAppts = OLAppts.Restrict(strRestriction)

    'Construct filter for Subject containing 'Client'
    Const PropTag  As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
    strRestriction = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & PropTag _
                        & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " like '%Client%'"

    ' Filter the collection to include only the day's appointments
    Set OLAppts = OLAppts.Restrict(strRestriction)

    ' Sort it again to put recurring appointments in correct order
    OLAppts.Sort "[Start]"

    With OLAppts
        ' capture subject, start time and duration of each item
        Set OLAppt = .GetFirst

        Do While TypeName(OLAppt) <> "Nothing"
            r = Last(1, .Columns("G")) + 1

            '- Client - HSBC - Trade Reporting
            '#   Employee    Date    Start   End Client  Agenda  Location

            If InStr(LCase(OLAppt.Subject), "client") > 0 Then
                strList = Split(OLAppt.Subject, "-")
                .Range("F" & r).Value = r - 1
                .Range("G" & r).Value = strUserName
                .Range("H" & r).Value = Format(dtStartAppt, "d-mmm-yyyy")
                .Range("I" & r).Value = OLAppt.Start
                .Range("J" & r).Value = OLAppt.End
                .Range("K" & r).Value = Trim(CStr(strList(1)))
                .Range("L" & r).Value = Trim(CStr(strList(2)))
                .Range("J" & r).Value = OLAppt.Location

            End If
            Set OLAppt = .GetNext
        Loop
    End With
End With

 ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OLAppt = Nothing
    Set OLAppts = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & C_Procedure & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

Comment: The code always returns "Calendar not shared"!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `On Error Resume Next` (the one below `With ws`) and post the line where the code is failing.

Also, you mentioned Outlook is run on a Citrix server. I hope you're running this script in the same instance where Outlook is running otherwise I'm not sure how you expect communication with the Outlook instance would happen.

I also hope you do have access to the shared calendar, something you didn't explicitly mention.